# vhdl code (while loop)

Tags: while-loop, vhdl

description:
I would like to write a vhdl while loop that will find the largest integer in an array [A] of 20 integers.

Question:
what should my algorithm look like, to input where the sequential statements are?

My vhdl code:

```
highnum: WHILE i LOOP
if 
(arr[i]>arr[HighestSoFar]){HighestSoFar=i;}20
i<= i + 1;
end if;
exit;
END LOOP highnum;
```

This does not need to be synthesizable but I dont know how to form this for loop, in fact im not sure what the syntax would look like. a detailed example explaining how to would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for "possible" duplicate :D

Comment: I am not sure how to begin other then the code I provided above. and no it does not need to be synthesizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting examples. Wikibooks has [plenty of examples](http://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_VHDL/Arquitectura):

The for loop structure:

```
[label:] [WHILE <condition> | FOR <condition>] LOOP
   [statements]
   [exit;]
   [next;]
 END LOOP [label];
```

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Don't.

`While` loops have no fixed bound on the number of iterations of the loop. Any attempt to synthesise them would have to generate a runtime-variable amount of hardware : hopefully you can see this as absurd until we learn to make dynamically growing FPGAs.

As it doesn't have to be synthesisable you CAN use a `While` loop and it will work pretty much as you would expect if you have used other programming languages, but it offers no advantages *for this task* over the `For` loop.

So use a `For` loop instead.

Comment: "until we learn to make dynamically growing FPGAs" - I'll be waiting. ;)